# Get int user input in java using delimiters and hasNext?

Tags: java, string, int, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useDelimiter(", "); // using delimiter ", "

    int i = 1;
    while(in.hasNextInt()){
        i = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

**I am trying to get the input from console, but this code is**
**[not printing last integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc2UJ.png)**
How can I solve this problem. I don't want to use split and save the result in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a regex pattern.

```
in.useDelimiter(",?\\s");
```

OR, if it is not necessarily seperated by both spaces and commas (e.g. `1, 4,5465, 5`):

```
in.useDelimiter("[,\\s]+"); // this is more permissive
```

Comment: You tried a wrong pattern, it will not use **","** as delimiter i.e try **1,     4,5465, 5** as input, you'll get **1,4,5,4,6,5,5** as output

Comment: @negia Yeah, I realized that just now, I removed the * (damn! it didn't go unnoticed :)).

Answer (score 0):

With `Scanner.useDelimiter`, the string after your last input integer should match the delimiter pattern, for example with your pattern if you give `"1, 3, 5, 6, "` you will get `1 3 5 6` as output but if you give `"1, 3, 5, 6"` you will not get the last integer.